# Input overflows container

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where setting `width: 100%` to inputs inside a container extends more than the container capacity. This problem doesn't seems to happen with buttons though:

```
<form>    
  <input type="text" class="input"></input>    
  <button>Button</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form {
  max-width: 200px;  
  border: 1px solid #eee;   
}

.input, button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

In this example, the button correctly fills the container, however the input extends a bit further:

[image]

How can I fix this?

I've created a codepen: http://codepen.io/jviotti/pen/qfFmH

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can fix this with the `box-sizing` property like this :

```
.input, button {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* <- add this */
}
```

box-sizing - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @Paulie_D thx for the codepen, and the vendor prefix suggestion, I updated my answer but I would rather set it on the `.input,button` rather than on `*` witch may have some performance issues.

Comment: The perfomnace issue you mentioned has been the subject of some discussion and found not to be significant factor.